# how to write the cron expression, fire at two timing

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Fire at `7:10am on MON-FRI` and at 7:20am on SAT every month.

1. 0 10 7 ? * TUE-FRI
2. 0 20 7 ? * SAT

How to write **one** cron expression to implement.Is there any approach to merge 1 and 2?

Create other trigger is a bit ugly.

Currently,my class extends **org.quartz.CronTrigger** .And the xml file like below.

```
<bean id="tradeReportJobTrigger" parent="abstractTrigger">
    <property name="job" ref="tradeReportJob"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 9 ? * TUE-SAT"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of `cron` I think you'll need the two entries to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [Quartz Scheduler 2.0 API](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) page describing Cron Expressions, the answer in Quartz Scheduler is similar to the answer in regular `cron`:

- No; you cannot combine the two expressions into one single one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to combine this into a single expression. How about adding a second CronTrigger Bean refering to the same job?